# C# ListBox Paint Event

Tags: listbox, paint

Is it possible to use a linear gradient brush to paint the background of a list box?  If so how do I raise the paint event to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try responding (or overriding) to the OnPaintBackground event.  You shouldn't need to do anything too special.

Comment: How can I do that with a list box when it doesn't have an actual paint event that I can see?

Comment: It inherits from Control, which does.